# Fourier transform step-by-step example: $f(x) = 1/2$ where $x\in[0,1]$ otherwise $f(x) = 0$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to understand the general procedure for finding the fourier transform of a function f(x). I've seen the general theory, but feel It would help with a concrete example to see how it is applied in practice.

So wondering what a step-by-step procedure for transforming the below is?

$f(x) = 1/2$ where $x\in[0,1]$  otherwise $f(x) = 0$
How would the procedure differ if the interval for x was $x\in[-1,1]$ instead?

**Added:**

As I understand it after some more checking we would get, from what i've seen a procedure as follows for the first interval. Where F is the Fourier-transformation of f:

$F(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i w x} dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} e^{-i w x} dx = \frac{i}{4\pi w}(e^{-iw} - 1)$

Comment: What interval are you expanding over? If you are expanding over $[-\pi,\pi]$, then you use functions $\{ e^{inx}\}$. If you are expanding over $[-1,1]$, then you use functions $\{ e^{in\pi x}\}$. It makes a difference.

Comment: I believe the interval would be the interval for x, otherwise there might be a standard interval used if that's not the right interval.

Comment: You have defined $f$ everywhere; that's an infinite interval.

Comment: Your integration result does not look correct.
$$\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^1 e^{-iwx} dx = \frac{i}{4\pi w}(e^{-iw} - 1)$$

Comment: @TrialAndError: Your comment applies to Fourier series, but the OP is evaluating a Fourier transform.

Comment: @Bungo : Ah, I misread. Thank you.

Comment: @Trial: Thx, corrected the mistake.